# Makes several queries at the same in a server a get the first response

Tags: haskell

I would like to make several queries (send POST request) at the same time.
And stay with the first answer that has a certain pattern (e.g The page shows Ok).

The web page that I'm trying to consult could take so much time to respond depends on the data sent. Therefore, I am interested in those requests that give me an answer first. The rest request I should finish them.

How can I do such a thing in Haskell?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that uses `wreq` to send POST requests and async to run them in parallel and return the first one to complete (cancelling the others).

Note, this example is executable via a `stack` shebang.

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
    --resolver lts-6.12
    --install-ghc
    runghc
    --package aeson
    --package conceit
    --package lens
    --package lens-aeson
    --package wreq
-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Concurrent.Conceit
import Control.Lens
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Lens (key)
import Data.Maybe (maybe)
import Data.Foldable
import Network.Wreq

echo :: Integer -> IO (Either Value String)
echo i = do
  r <- post "http://httpbin.org/post" (toJSON i)
  if i >= 3 && i <= 8 then pure $ Right "simulate failure"
  else pure $ maybe (Right "Malformed response") Left (r ^? responseBody . key "json")

main = do
  first <- mapConceit echo [1..10]
  print first
```

Comment: What if one request completes but doesn't have "Ok" in the body?

Comment: If you don't get an "Ok", you can `throwIO "failed"`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, simply throwing an exception to indicate that you didn't get an "Ok" does not work as all threads get automatically cancelled.

Comment: I got a working code example using @danidiaz's `conceit` package.

Answer (score 2):

The [async](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async) package provides useful functions that return the result of the first concurrent action that completes ([`race`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:race)) or wait for all the actions to complete and return the aggregate result ([`concurrently`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:concurrently), `mapConcurrently`).

However, this tidbit in your question:

> And stay with the first answer that has a certain pattern (e.g The
>   page shows Ok).

complicates things a little, because when one of your POST request completes, it can either trigger the cancellation of the others (if Ok is found) or not trigger it (if Ok is not found).

I had a similar problem, and didn't find a *direct* way of doing this with the "async" package that didn't involve throwing exceptions.

I ended up creating the [conceit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conceit) package to handle this. You can use the [`mapConceit`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conceit-0.4.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-Conceit.html#v:mapConceit) function:

```
mapConceit :: Traversable t => (a -> IO (Either e b)) -> t a -> IO (Either e (t b))
```

Where `t a` will be your list of urls, `e` the result when Ok is found in the page, and `b` the result when it isn't. If any of the concurrent `IO` actions returns with `Left e`, the others will be immediately cancelled and the composite action will return with `Left e`.

An alternative is to use `mapConcurrently` from "async", and when the Ok is found, throw an custom exception carrying your result value. But I don't like to use exceptions for returning results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a library function to do this, but here's a sketch of a solution using “[async](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async)” that assumes uninteresting answers will raise an exception.

```
racing :: [Async a] -> IO a
racing actions = do
    first <- waitAnyCatch actions
    case first of
      (action, Left  _) -> racing (delete action actions)
      (action, Right a) -> mapM_ cancel (delete action actions) >> return a
```